# GL Math : GLM rotate function rotates the entire coordinate system

Tags: c++, opengl, glm-math

I did the following transformations:

```
// Translate my cube to origin
myCubeModelMatrix = glm::translate( myCubeModelMatrix, vec3(-pos.x, -pos.y , -pos.z) ) ;

// Rotate cube about Y axis
myCubeModelMatrix = glm::rotate( myCubeModelMatrix , vec3(0,1,0) ) ;

// Translate back to original position
myCubeModelMatrix = glm::translate( myCubeModelMatrix, vec3(pos.x, pos.y , pos.z) ) ;
```

**The Problem:**
The second step, where I rotate the cube, it's actually rotating the entire coordinate system. Because of that, the third step fails to bring back my cube to the original position.

**Observed output:**
*Initial position of cube:* X,Y,Z
*Position after translation to Origin :* 0,0,0
*Position after rotating about Y Axis :* 0,0,0
*Position after "trying" to translate back to original position:* SomeOtherX, Y, SomeOtherZ

Note that after the final reverse translation, the X and Z coordinates are now different from the original, while the Y coordinate is same as original. So my inference is that the rotation about the Y axis has actually rotated the entire coordinate system, and thus the X and Z have changed, but Y hasn't.

What am I doing wrong here? All my arbitrary axis rotations will fail if the rotation does this.

Comment: This question is off-topic because it's related to maths, not programming.

Comment: This question is about how a popular math library is behaving. The math is clear here.

Comment: @sanjeevmk: If the math were clear to you, you wouldn't multiply the matrices in the wrong order :)

Comment: @derhass Yeah, I know I am doing something wrong, but that doesn't make this a "non programming" question. A programming question can be  about math, logic or anything else inside a program. Anyway, should I be doing it in the reverse order?

Comment: @sanjeevmk: Well. I'd like to avoid a philosphical discussion about waht a programming question is. I can see arguments for both sides here. However, the key point is that you actually got the math wrong. Yes, reversing the order of that 3 transformations is likely to solve the issue.

Comment: @derhass Thanks, reverse computations helped! :)

Answer (score 1):

You are not specifing the amount of rotation in the Y axis,
and if you already cache the position and the rotation the you can use somthing like this.

```
glm::mat4 translation = glm::translate(glm::mat4(), glm::vec3(pos.x, pos.y, pos.z));
glm::mat4 rotation = glm::rotate(glm::mat4(), rotationAmount, glm::vec3(0, 1, 0));

myCubeModelMatrix = translation * rotation;
```

of course you can optimize it, but i never used glm, so thats up to you.